# Pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyscreeze

Im having issues with pyautogui.

```
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
  File "C:\Users\maxwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1759, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel(
NameError: name 'pyscreeze' is not defined
```

I've done research on pyscreeze and i don't know what the issue is, everything should be installed correctly and pyautogui does work in some cases

```
pyautogui.displayMousePosition
<function displayMousePosition at 0x000001D6E8C95760>
```

both with "import pyautogui"
Im just tryna figure out my mouse position so i can write a program with clicking, am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try this instead: `print(pyautogui.position())` to display the mouse position.

Comment: i also made sure pyscreeze was installed with pip from CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it works in the second case is that you are printing the displayMousePosition *attribute* of pyautogui instead of calling the function; the printed
`<function displayMousePosition at 0x000001D6E8C95760>`   tells you that `displayMousePosition`  is a function.
However, if you add the parenthesis,
`pyautogui.displayMousePosition()`
you effectively call this function, wich relies on pyscreeze, and since there is apparently an issue in your installation with this module you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to get a screenshot instead of real-time coordinates printed to console. For that you can try:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.mouseInfo()
```